# CSS custom not added

Tags: magento2, theme, css, xml, custom

I have this structure :

```
|-app/design/frontend
 |-Magento
   |-Theme
     |-layout
       |--default.xml
       |--default_head_blocks.xml
     |-Magento_Theme 
       |-templates 
     |-web
       |-css
         |--custom-m.css
       |-js
   |-theme.xml
   |-requirejs-config.js
   |-registration.php
```

In default.xml :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Script" name="requirejs" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <!-- RequireJs library enabled -->
                    <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">requirejs/require.js</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <!-- Special block with necessary config is added on the page -->
            <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config" after="requirejs"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <remove name="report.bugs"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

And in default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
        <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" src_type="url"/>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url"/>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous" src_type="url"/>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous" src_type="url"/>
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom-m.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.polyfill" as="polyfill" template="Magento_Theme::js/polyfill.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="head.components" as="components" template="Magento_Theme::js/components.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But my custom-m.css in not detected. Any ideas ?

**EDIT :**

In fact, the problem is from my default_head_blocks.xml. Bootstrap is not charging inside this (i added cdn in phtml file, but i forgot), so i'll try to figure out the problem

Comment: Try placing your "layout" folder inside the "Magento_Theme" directory

Comment: Not working with this :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try following ways

```
 <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
        <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" src_type="url"/>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url"/>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous" src_type="url"/>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous" src_type="url"/>
        <css src="css/custom-m.css"/>
    </head>
```

***css/custom-m.css*** Must be under ***app/design/frontend/package/themename/web/css*** directory.

Now run code into cli

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f  //production mode
```

Then make clear cache & permission of generating folders

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static generated/
```

*Let me know if fixed.*

Comment: Not changing (i'm in developer mode)

Comment: open browser console. check any 404 error

Comment: also check store code.....
IF you are using different store 
Need to run 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US  ar_SA -f  like that.

Comment: No error 404, this css file not detected at all.
I'm only using 1 store

Comment: what is your parent theme?

Comment: open this location & check 
pub/static/frontend/packagename/themename/en_US/Magento_Theme/css

exist or not.

Comment: my parent theme is luma

Comment: There's no css folder !

Comment: Try improve ans.

Comment: I did this : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR -f, now i have the css folder but the css is still not detected

Comment: Make an permission 
chmod 777 -R pub/static/frontend if css is created & try flush of cache.

Comment: Already done that

Comment: great, well done!!!

Comment: But it still not working. In fact, it looks like it's my default_head_blocks.xml that is not working. Bootstrap is not loading through CDN inside this XML

Comment: please check console what is the error ??

Comment: I found what was wrong. I had to move layout in Magento_Theme, remove all the CDN et remove the "remove" part of default.xml

Comment: default.xml use for all pages but default_head_blocks.xml use for head block in m2

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the layout in the following format,

```
 |-app/design/frontend
  |-Magento
    |-Theme
      |-Magento_Theme 
        |-layout
          |--default.xml
          |--default_head_blocks.xml
        |-templates 
      |-web
        |-css
          |--custom-m.css
        |-js
      |-theme.xml
      |-requirejs-config.js
      |-registration.php
```

After placing, Clear cache

try changing `<css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom-m.css"/>` to `<css src="css/custom-m.css"/>` in default_head_blocks.xml

Comment: Not changing, already tried

Comment: Have you tried changing <css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom-m.css"/> to <css src="css/custom-m.css"/> in default_head_blocks.xml

Comment: Yes, still not working

Comment: @MorganTartreau Please check active theme from backend !

Comment: It's working in backend

Comment: @MorganTartreau, Have you checked the "theme" table for your custom theme type? Check if the theme is not virtual i.e., 0 for physical.